# How to make code after reading from the database occur after the read has occurred

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

When testing my code the console logs will be `2: 0` (multiple times), `3: 0` (once), `1: _` (multiple times where `_` increases each time).

I am unsure as to how to get `1` to occur before `2` and `3` so that when I write to the database (after log 3) the value isn't `0`.

I am unsure how to approach this problem as I am inexperienced with firebase.

```
  var count=0;
  var total=0;

  var ass_ref = admin.database().ref("modules/"+mod+"/Assignments");
  return ass_ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {

    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {

      var name = child.key;

      var ref = admin.database().ref("modules/"+mod+"/Assignments/"+name+"/"+uid);
      ref.once("value", function(mark) {

          count++;
          total=total+ parseInt(mark.val(),10);
          console.log("1:"+total);  //Value increases each time but occurs after 3

      });

      console.log("2:"+total);  //Value = 0 (occurs multiple times, in foreach)

    });

    console.log("3:"+total);  //Value = 0, logs once, after "2"
```

I desire `1` to occur before `2` (I believe it would log as 1,2,1,2...) so that the final value logged at `3` matches the last value logged at `1`.

Comment: I suggest learning how to work with promises to do asynchronous programming in JavaScript. `once()` returns a promise - learn how to use that. There is an introduction on using promises in Cloud Functions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for the assistance, the videos proved helpful once I got a better understanding of promises.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my working solution, it is probably not optimal but does the job.
Thanks to Doug Stevenson for providing a link to helpful learning material.
This similar post proved very helpful: [Promise.all with Firebase DataSnapshot.forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879695/promise-all-with-firebase-datasnapshot-foreach)

```
...

var ref = admin.database().ref("modules/"+mod+"/Assignments");

return ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    var reads = [];

    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var id = childSnapshot.key;

        var ref = admin.database().ref("modules/"+mod+"/Assignments/"+id+"/"+uid);
        var promise = ref.once("value", function(mark) {
            // The Promise was fulfilled.
        }, function(error) {
            // The Promise was rejected.
            console.error(error);
        });
        reads.push(promise);
    });
    return Promise.all(reads);

}, function(error) {
    // The Promise was rejected.
    console.error(error);
}).then(function(values) { 
    total=0;
    count = values.length
    values.forEach(snap => {
      var data = parseInt(snap.node_.value_)
      total=total+data
    })
    var average = total/count;
    console.log(total)
    console.log(count)
    console.log(average)

    var reads = [];
    var p1 =admin.database().ref('/student/'+uid+"/modules/"+mod).set(average);
    var p2 =admin.database().ref('/student/'+uid+'/points/grades').transaction(function(prev){
      return parseInt(total,10)+score;
    });
    reads.push(p1);
    reads.push(p2);
    return Promise.all(reads);

});
```