# How to wait array until complete, then execute the function?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

i have some trouble.
I want my function execute when my array is complete.
But the my function execute although my array is not complete.
can you fix my code please..

```
const historyPermintaanObat2 = obat => {
let array = [];
db.child("itemPermintaan")
  .orderByChild("id")
  .equalTo(obat.id)
  .on("child_added", snapshot => {
    let obj = snapshot.val();
    let registerPermintaanRef = db.child(
      `registerPermintaan/${obj.idPermintaan}`
    );
    registerPermintaanRef.once("value", snap => {
      let username = snap.val().username;
      let createdAt = snap.val().createdAt;
      let approvedAt = snap.val().approvedAt;
      let unit = snap.val().unit;
      let obj2 = { ...obj, username, createdAt, approvedAt, unit };
      array.push(obj2);

    });
  });
return array;
};
```

The result is `[]` empty array.
If i change the `return array.length > 0 && array` nothing is happen..

Comment: In your first query, you should use `once()` instead of `on()`, so you can get a promise that resolves when the query is complete.  Use these promises (chaining both calls to `once()`) to return another promise that the caller can use the get the desired value.

Comment: you should mention their username with @ symbol if you want them to be notified when you comment dear moh jonaidy; like this @DougStevenson

Comment: @DougStevenson i had tried your suggestion, but the result is empty array [ ]. The problem is, if i execute my function twice, then it will get some array. i want my function execute once, await until the array complete then outcome the result.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out, use `once` and `Promise.all()`

```
const historyPermintaanObat2 = obat => {
db.child("itemPermintaan")
  .orderByChild("id")
  .equalTo(obat.id)
  .once("value", snapshot => {
    let array = [];
    let obj = Object.values(snapshot.val());
    obj.forEach(e => {
      let registerPermintaanRef = db.child(
        `registerPermintaan/${e.idPermintaan}`
      );
      let promise = registerPermintaanRef.once("value").then(snap => {
        let username = snap.val().username;
        let createdAt = snap.val().createdAt;
        let approvedAt = snap.val().approvedAt;
        let unit = snap.val().unit;
        let obj2 = { ...e, username, createdAt, approvedAt, unit };
        return obj2;
      });
      array.push(promise);
    });
    return Promise.all(array).then(value => {
      return value;
    });
  });
 };
```

Here's the reference i've got [Promise.all with Firebase DataSnapshot.forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879695/promise-all-with-firebase-datasnapshot-foreach)