# Can't iterate through array from an async Javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck on an issue where I'm parsing the results from an API in `getSubscriptions()`.  This calls `getUserSubs()` which returns the following object:

[image: expected result]

When I call on `subscriptions` I get the expected array console (See "Works") snippet.

But when I try to iterate on the array `subscriptions` (See "Doesn't work"), then the contents of the function are not even called.

### userSubs() is called for API data

```js
async function getUserSubs(userId) {
  const ref = collection(db, "users", userId, "subscriptions")
  let subList = []
  try {
    const subIds = await getDocs(ref)
    subIds.forEach(subRef => {
      const docRef = subRef.data()
      getDocData(docRef.product).then(product => {
        subList.push(product)
      })
    })
    return subList

  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error in getting subscriptions: ", e)
    return []
  }
}
```

### Works

```js
function getSubscriptions(userId) {
  getUserSubs(userId).then(subscriptions => {
    console.log(subscriptions)  // Works as intended 
  }
}
```

### Doesn't work

```js
function getSubscriptions(userId) {
  getUserSubs(userId).then(subscriptions => {
    subscriptions.forEach(x => {
      console.log(x)  // ISSUE: This isn't called 
    })
}
```

### Also doesn't work

```js
let a = []
getUserSubs(userId).then(subscriptions => {
  subscriptions.forEach(x => a.push(x))
})
console.log(a)
```

I know there are similar questions asked but after reading them I'm still not able to resolve my issue.

Similar issues:

- [How to access the value of a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29516390)
- [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37576685)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include data as text, rather than a picture of text. It would probably be easiest if you use `console.log(JSON.stringify(variable, null, 2))` and pasted the result here. Then we wouldn't need to see all of the `[[Prototype]]` nonsense :).

Comment: The contents of the array returned are objects, not arrays. An object does not have a `.forEach()` method. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: I've tried to mock AJAX call, you can clearly see, It is working as expected [link](https://codepen.io/kumarmasterpraveen/pen/KKXaLEG?editors=0011)

Comment: Do read [weird array behaviour in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49838597/215552) for more information about why using `console.log` works and what that `i` means.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron for why your third attempt doesn't work.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for the tip! But it seems this function isn't called when I place in the `then()` function: `getUserSubs(userId).then(subscriptions => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(subscriptions, null, 4))
  })`

Comment: Once again: if you iterate through that array, each array element will be an object. You cannot use `.forEach()` to iterate through an object.

Comment: @Pointy `JSON.stringify` works on objects and arrays; I was hoping that it would definitively say what type of thing `subscriptions` is. I think there's something else going on here that we can't see. Perhaps in `getUserSubs`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey well I was going by the image posted in the question.

Comment: I didn't think it be important but I now added the userSubs() function.  I appreciate all of you! :)

Comment: I used `typeof(subscriptions)` and it returned `object`.  So @Pointy has... a point.  But the successful output has brackets and an index number, so wouldn't that be an array?

Comment: The outer object returned is an array, but you're trying to put a `.forEach` inside the outer `.forEach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> getUserSubs(userId).then(subscriptions => {
>     console.log(subscriptions)  // Works as intended 
> }
> ```

No it doesn't. It only appears so because [you are inspecting the live array that was mutated after it has been logged to the console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440/1048572).

> Also doesn't work:
>
> ```
> let a = []
> getUserSubs(userId).then(subscriptions => {
>   subscriptions.forEach(x => a.push(x))
> })
> console.log(a)
> ```

Yes, for rather [obvious reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron): the array is logged before you fill it. It would need to be either

```
getUserSubs(userId).then(subscriptions => {
  let a = []
  subscriptions.forEach(x => a.push(x))
  console.log(a)
})
```

or

```
let a = []
const subscriptions = await getUserSubs(userId)
subscriptions.forEach(x => a.push(x))
console.log(a)
```

---

But none of these will solve your core problem: `getUserSubs` returns an empty array before it gets filled, in the lines

```
subIds.forEach(subRef => {
  const docRef = subRef.data()
  getDocData(docRef.product).then(product => {
    subList.push(product)
  })
})
return subList
```

you never wait for the `getDocData` promise. If you change that to

```
let subList = []
for (const subRef of subIds) {
  const docRef = subRef.data()
  const product = await getDocData(docRef.product)
  subList.push(product)
}
return subList
```

or just

```
return Promise.all(subIds.map(subRef => {
  const docRef = subRef.data()
  return getDocData(docRef.product)
}))
```

it would work, as described in [the question you already found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37576685).

(This might still not work. `subIds` looks suspiciously like a firebase snapshot, which is not an array and can neither be iterated nor does it have a `.map` method. In that case, you'll need to [use `forEach`+`push` manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35879766/1048572)).

Comment: But shouldn't the `getUserSubs()` be fine since I do get a result (top screenshot) but I just can't seem to iterate through it?  Which is your last point because yes I'm using Firebase v9 so I'll have to adapt the answer.

Comment: @engineer-x No, you're not getting a result, the array is empty when you get it. Iterating it immediately will iterate 0 entries.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I wouldn't use the forEach() method. I think all you need to do to fix this is iterate over the results in a normal for loop.

```
for(let subscription of subscriptions) {
   console.log(subscription);
}

OR

for(let index in subscriptions) {
   console.log(subscriptions[index]);
}
```

If this doesn't do the trick, I'll open up a sandbox and look more in depth.

Comment: Mind If you could explain *I wouldn't use the forEach() method* What's wrong with `forEach` if `subscriptions` is an array...

Comment: BTW, You shouldn't use `for..in` loop with arrays.

Comment: @decpk I added the expected result in the original question.

Comment: @edward I tried both and still had the same result.  I also tried the `for (let i = 0; i < subscriptions.length; subscriptions++)`.

Comment: Ok please edit your post with the array that's going wrong and I'll put them into a sandbox. As to why I wouldn't use the forEach method, I guess it really comes down to personal preference but I think the for loops using of and in are cleaner but anecdotally, I've run into instances where forEach failed when for loops didn't.